# Rails3 routing error with ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

***UPDATED CODE at the bottom***

I am creating a story voting app via Simply Rails 2 book. I am getting this error when I click the button to vote up a story:

`No route matches "/stories/4-pure-css-icons-showcase"`

My routing file looks like this:

```
Shovell::Application.routes.draw do
  get "votes/create"

  root :to => "stories#index"
  resources :stories do
    resources :votes
  end
end
```

votes_controller.rb:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @story.votes.create
  end

end
```

create.rsj :

```
page.replace_html 'vote_score', "Score: #{@story.votes.size}"
page[:vote_score].visual_effect :highlight
```

show.html.erb:

```
<h2>
    <span id="vote_score">
        Score: <%= @story.votes.size %>
    </span>
    <%= @story.name %>
</h2>
<p>
    <%= link_to @story.link, @story.link %>
</p>
<div id="vote_form">
    <%= form_tag :url => story_votes_path(@story), :remote => true do %>
        <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

story.rb :

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :link
    has_many :votes
    def to_param
        "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
    end
end
```

I've been working through a number of other errors before this having to do with deprecated code and so forth, so I feel somewhat lost at the moment. It seems like it should just be a routing a issue, but since I've been working through AJAX errors that also have to do with the vote function I wanted to post those files just in case it was more than routing.

It says no route matches `"/stories/4-pure-css-icons-showcase"` but when I visit `"/stories"` (my root) and click on the link to take me to `"/stories/4-pure-css-icons-showcase"` it works fine, however after clicking on the vote button I get this error. As you could probably tell after reading the code, it is suppose to update the vote count and do a `:highlight` via ajax.

---

**UPDATE:**

Changed code (all changes are per Sam's advice):

routes:

```
Shovell::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :votes
  root :to => "stories#index"
  resources :stories do
    resources :votes
  end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<div id="vote_form">
    <%= form_tag :url => new_story_vote_path(@story), :remote => true do %>
        <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

votes_controller.rb

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
    @story.votes.create
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js 
  end
end
```

The problem is still exactly the same, but I think (read: hope) we are making progress!

**The scenario:** My index (`/stories`) page randomly displays a story from the database, when you click the link it takes you to the story's internal page (ex. `/stories/2-sitepoint-forums`) on this page it displays the number of votes the story has and has a button to vote for it. When you click the vote button it is suppose to use ajax to update the `@story.vote.size` and use a `:highlight` visual effect. However, the problem is that when you click the vote button the page changes to a "Routing Error" page which displays:

`No route matches "/stories/2-sitepoint-forums"`

Its weird to me because you can in fact be routed to that address and you are from the link on the first page...

---

**Here is the error in the console:**

```
Started POST "/stories/2-sitepoint-forums?url=%2Fstories%2F2-sitepoint-forums%2F
votes%2F2-sitepoint-forums&remote=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-08 16:30:17 -08
00

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stories/2-sitepoint-forums"):



Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.0.rc2/lib/action_dis
patch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0m
s)
```

Im not sure if this is any more telling, but I thought I'd add it incase.

---

**New:**
I have not been able to solve this problem as of yet. Because I still don't feel like I completely understand the issue I have decided to move over to the Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial Book online and see if I can't figure it out while working through it. Since I was planning to do it next anyway (I have plans to combine both apps later) it appears now is the time.

Comment: can you restate exactly what the problem is below your updated code?

Comment: Updated with a description of the scenario and exact problem

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= form_tag :url => new_story_vote_path(@story), :remote => true do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
<% end %>
```

That should send it to the create action.

```
def create
  @story = Story.find(params[:story_id])
  @story.votes.create
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js 
  end 
end
```

And that should take care of your ajax.

---

take this `get "votes/create"` out of your routes

and add this

```
map.resources :votes
```

Comment: Should it be create_story_vote_path? Other than that, looks good. The original problem here was POSTing to a GET URL, I think.

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I tried exactly what Sam said as well as what Paul commented. Furthermore, I changed `vote` to `votes` on both just to be sure and it didnt help. A question though: I do not have a format.html or format.js should I?

Comment: `"map."` was changed in Rails3 so I did the equivalent `resources :votes` and now I have a new error, Ill update the main post with it.

Comment: When I wrote the above comment I was getting an error loading the original story page, but after I wrote the above comment I changed the other code back to the way Sam mentioned (I had been experimenting) and now the story page loads fine, but I am getting the exact same error as I was originally.

Comment: Read ahead a little more in my book and it actually had me adding the `format.html` and `format.js` so I now know what they are for and that they are not filenames! :)

Comment: I actually used that book to. It's really a good intro. The first thing I did do however was fix all the mistakes with the code updates on their website.

Comment: Yeah, Ive changed everything so far, unfortunately this problem doesn't stem from an error in the book...or at least I don't think it does. I haven't been using the code archive, maybe ill check against that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using form_tag and :remote (as I normally just write jQuery for stuff like this) but a couple of things definitely pop out at me with what you're doing here that may help you resolve the issue.

First of all, I think you can rework the way you set up a vote and thus the way you set up the form for the vote.  In the stories controller, for the show action, I'd set up the vote right away:

```
@vote = Vote.new(:story_id => @story.id)
```

This lets you set up your form as so:

```
= form_for(@vote), :remote => true do |f|
    = hidden_field f.story_id
    = submit_tag "Vote"
```

This is both a cleaner way of doing things, in my opinion, but also may fix the general issue you are dealing with, because you are now **passing data** with the form (the hidden field) in your POST request.  Rails will behave unexpectedly if you perform AJAX POST requests that do not actually submit data.

In other words, your original form is likely running as an AJAX POST request but it would have worked better as an AJAX GET request, since it is not actually submitting data, it is simply "hitting" an URL.

Comment: Should'nt anything that affects the state of the database be done via `POST` (and `DELETE/PUT` if it were an option!) instead of `GET` ?

Comment: When I say "worked better" I mean, it would have actually worked from a technical perspective, not that it necessarily ought to have been done that way. He routed a GET request but created a form that POSTed, which is probably the original root issue. Note that my suggested solution is a POST request and that's how it ought be done from a resource perspective.

Comment: I am new to programming as this is the first language I am attempting to learn. I don't fully understand what you're saying about GET and POST and such, but I will take more time to understand it tomorrow. I am more worried about coding it with best practices right now than simply getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found the answer to your problem yet, but I wanted to post for others that may be looking for an answer similar to yours.

The code:

```
<%= form_tag :url => new_story_vote_path(@story), :remote => true do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
<% end %>
```

will result in /stories/:story_id/votes/new url with a :post request.  It won't work because the `new` route is a :get method request. If you wanted to go to the `new` method, you'll need to tell the form to use the get http method.

```
<%= form_tag :url => new_story_vote_path(@story), :remote => true, :html => { :method => :get } do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
<% end %>
```

However, I think that you are wanting to route to the `create` method in your controller.  I would do something like:

```
<%= form_tag :url => story_votes_path(@story), :remote => true do %>
    <%= submit_tag 'shove it' %>
<% end %>
```

This should route correctly to the `create` method in your VotesController.